# How to Get the Rows of Master table only if Details table satisfies Condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetOrdersList]
   @OrderID int = NULL,
   @UserID int = NULL,
   @IsCompleted smallint = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    select 
       tto.OrderID, tto.DateAdded, tto.ItemsCount, tto.TotalAmount,
       ttu.FirstName, ttu.LastName, ttu.Email,
       ISNULL(ttu.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(ttu.LastName,'') FullUserName,
       tuq.QuoteStatusID
    from 
       tbl_Orders tto 
    join 
       tbl_Users ttu on tto.UserID = ttu.UserID
    where 
       tto.OrderID = ISNULL(@OrderID,tto.OrderID)
       AND tto.UserID = ISNULL(@TronixUserID,tto.TronixUserID)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM tbl_UserQuotes ttuq
                   WHERE ttuq.OrderID = tto.OrderID
                     AND ttuq.QuoteStatusID = ISNULL(@IsCompleted, ttuq.QuoteStatusID)
                  )
    --QuoteStatusID: 4.Completed other than 4 are Pending/Incomplete/Processing
END
```

Here in above query I want to fetch the all the records from table `tbl_Orders` only if all the rows in the `tbl_UserQuotes` table have `QuoteStatusID = 4` i.e `Completed`. If even a single row is other than 4 then it must not appear into list.

```
MasterTable(tbl_Orders)
OrderID ITemsCount TotalAmount
  1       1          100
  2       2          200
  3       2          300

DetailTable(tbl_UserQuotes)
DetailID  OrderID    Amount QuoteStatusID
  1         1         100      4
  2         2         100      2
  3         2         100      4 
  4         3         150      4
  5         3         150      4


Result Must be:
OrderID TotalAmount
  1        100
  3        300
```

Comment: why u not sumed orderid=2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is My Solution:

```
  Select tto.OrderID,tto.DateAdded,tto.ItemsCount,tto.TotalAmount,
    ttu.FirstName,ttu.LastName,ttu.Email ,ISNULL(ttu.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(ttu.LastName,'') FullUserName

    from tbl_Orders tto join tbl_Users ttu 
    on tto.UserID = ttu.UserID

    where tto.OrderID = ISNULL(@OrderID,tto.OrderID)
    AND tto.UserID = ISNULL(@UserID,tto.UserID)
    AND tto.ItemsCount= (
        select count(orderid) from tbl_UerQuotes where orderid=tto.OrderID and quotestatusid=4
        )
    ORDER BY tto.DateAdded DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query:

```
SELECT tbl_orders.orderid, 
       Sum(amount) 
FROM   tbl_orders 
       INNER JOIN tbl_userquotes 
               ON tbl_orders.orderid = tbl_userquotes.orderid 
WHERE  tbl_orders.orderid <> (SELECT orderid 
                              FROM   tbl_userquotes 
                              WHERE  quotestatusid <> 4) 
GROUP  BY tbl_orders.orderid
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2270b/1)**

Comment: yes this too works..but need to groupby one more table i.e tbl_Users..still thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please Try this query**     

select mt.orderId,sum(dt.amount) 
    from MasterTable as mt inner join DetailTable as dt on mt.orderid=dt.orderid
    group by orderid having quotestatusid=4
```